# Can a DHCP Client tell the DHCP Server not to hand him a specific IP address?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have a device that has two ports and one always requires static IP address "X". The other port can be connected to a LAN for internet access. Is it possible that when that port is configured via DHCP, to tell the DHCP server to forbid IP address "X" from being assigned to it?

Comment: You mean like a DHCP reservation… but in negative? It would be far simpler to just reserve an address, based on the MAC.

Comment: No, the whole point of DHCP is that the client provides no significant configuration, and leaves the locus of control on the server. create a reservation for X, and leave the other interface default. you could remove the Static config from X as well, once you have the reservation. that way you can centrally manage everything from the DHCP server.

Comment: Just forbidding one IP would be not enough. If an device has two interfaces each interface has to get an IP from a different subnet, hence if you have the problem that the static IP may collide with the addresses used by your DHCP server this means they r!e located in the same subnet. Reconfigure your DHCP to use a different subnet is the only clean solution.

Comment: Your DHCP server is giving addresses from a defined range... ie 1-254.  Just change it to a more realistic range for your use (ie. 100-200) and then assign the static address interface to a number outside of that range (ie 10)